# Is there a way for both the native C++ API and the managed C++\CLI API wrapping it to have the same names of namespaces and classes

Tags: c#, namespaces, c++-cli

**SYSTEM IN CONSIDERATION:**

API that provides both the native C++ and the managed interface to access it. Managed interface wraps the native one.

**THE GOAL:**

To have in both the native and the managed versions of API the same names of classes and variables - like `MyTech::Foo` for both API versions.

---

I'd like to do something like this :

```
namespace MyTech
{
   class Foo
   {
   public:
      Foo() { m_var = 1.0f; }
      float m_var;
   };

   public ref class Foo   // <----- class type redefinition error here
   {
      Foo(Foo *native)  
      {
         m_native = native;
      }

      Foo *m_native;
   };
}
```

.. but the compiler (visual studio 2013) barfs with a class type redefinition error.

I can see why, but would (if possible) like to keep class and namespaces identical across C++ and C#.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this by explicitly specifying whether I'm referring to C++ MyTech::Foo or C# MyTech::Foo ?

**WHAT HAVE BEEN TRIED:**

The best workaround I've found so far is to call the namespace mytech in C# and MyTech in C++ then the clash is avoided, but would prefer to keep them the same.

Comment: I'm unclear what having two C++ classes with the same name has to do with C# namespaces.

Comment: there aren't two C++ classes. one is C++, the other is C# (via the managed CLI implementation)

Comment: @SteveWilliams: `public ref class Foo` is not "a C# class".  It is a class with .NET metadata, and therefore visible to C#.  Since C++/CLI can consume both native and managed types, how would all the other C++/CLI code indicate which one it was working with?  In particular, the line `Foo *m_native;` is ambiguous.

Comment: @ben - understood. If not already implemented, I'd extend the language syntax.

Something like 

    native[Foo] *m_native;

maybe.

Comment: @Steve: Well, if you're willing to write `native[Foo]` every time you mean the native type, why aren't you willing to write `native_Foo` ?

Comment: Because native[Foo] would only be visible in the managed interface, which is internal code, so it doesn't matter that it's a necessarily verbose to avoid ambiguity. the bit I want to keep clean and ideally uniform is our external APIs - C++ and C#. not the end of the world if the namespaces have to be slightly different, but mild disappointment.

Comment: How about :


namespace MyTech
{
   class Foo  // implicitly MyTech::native::Foo
   {
  public:
   Foo() { m_var = 1.0f; }
   float m_var;
   };

   public ref class Foo  // implicitly MyTech::managed::Foo because of ref.
   {
      Foo(native::Foo *native)  
      {
         m_native = native;
      }

      native::Foo *m_native;
   };
}

and could write : class managed::Foo 
instead of      : ref class Foo 

.. and dump that ref from the syntax as it's confusing to have two ways to specify the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there exists such a way - C++\CLI treats managed and native classes as equal citizens of its namespaces.

**SO**

**1.** You could rename one of your classes

```
   class FooNative
   {
   public:
      Foo() { m_var = 1.0f; }
      float m_var;
   };

   public ref class Foo
   {
      Foo(FooNative* native)  
      {
         m_native = native;
      }
   };
```

**2.** Or just put them in different namespaces:

```
namespace MyTechNative
{
   class Foo
   {
   public:
      Foo() { m_var = 1.0f; }
      float m_var;
   };
}

// Another file

namespace MyTech
{    
   public ref class Foo 
   {
      Foo(MyTechNative::Foo *native)  
      {
         m_native = native;
      }
   };
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

**3.** You could try to use macroses. Something like:

```
#define LIB_NAME MyLib

// ------- Managed code - "Managed.h" ------

#define MANAGED_LIB_NAME LIB_NAME

#include "Native.h"    

namespace MANAGED_LIB_NAME 
{
    ...
    NATIVE_LIB_NAME::Foo* m_foo = new NATIVE_LIB_NAME::Foo();
}



// ------- Native code - "Native.h" -------

#ifdef MANAGED_LIB_NAME
    // Compile as inner code for managed assembly
    #define NATIVE_LIB_NAME MyLibNative
#else
    // Compile as C++ library
    #define NATIVE_LIB_NAME LIB_NAME
#endif

namespace NATIVE_LIB_NAME 
{
}
```

Essentially in this case you will have to organize two different compilations - one for clear native API, one for managed based on native, but you will avoid different namespaces in those APIs.

**P.S.:** There are some issues I still haven't considered deeply (include organization, include guards(#pragma once), one project or two...), but I doubt that there will be any real difficulties.

Comment: Thanks Eugene - you understand the problem & your suggested workarounds are the same as I've already considered. Think the slight change in namespace is cleaner as want to keep my C++ class names clean. Will be a shame if there's no way to keep the interfaces identically named.

Comment: Re: Your macro'd multiple compilation approach. Maybe some projects could use that approach but not this one. Both native & C# interfaces are available from the same runtime. The cleanest 'hack' for now appears to be the slight namespace change. They don't have to be identical, I'd just like them to be. Sounds like a language extension is required to address this properly as I suspected but wanted to run the issue past others to verify. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to provide both versions of API? C# programs will consume only the managed classes, C++ programs will use the native one. Why would any of them ever need to know about another API version?

Comment: You're right that they don't "know" about each other, which is why a slightly altered namespace is a suitable workaround. It's just cleaner to be able to name them the same. Its mainly a style issue rather than a technical obstacle. Will likely have to wait for a language specification upgrade. Got a workaround for the time being so that happens whenever.

Think of a browser (which, incidentally this is), you can code native plugins, you can script functionality. Want to keep both interfaces as close to each other as possible for maximum portability.

Comment: Your goal is to provide the same(or at least as close as possible) interface for your native and managed consumers. And the problem is that VC compiler and C++\CLI do not have any obvious ways to accomplish it. Solution 3 is cumbersome, but at least it may solve the problem. There may be some other way - C++ is very powerful language, but I'm not such a knowledgeable in it to see any other solutions for now.

Comment: Yeah, could maybe do some tricks to force a compile by changing the namespace as you say, then post process to link back up to the original one but that's likely more effort than it's worth. The language should support this so will run it past ms. A dummy C# namespace search & replace on the dll to put it back as intended or might work. More hacky than I'd like but so are many things when you want to push past the current spec.

Comment: tried hacking the namespace identifier in the managed code dll. no immediate joy. might be possible with more research.

Answer (score 0):

So, more of a proposal than an answer.

How about this :

```
namespace MyTech
{
   class Foo  // implicitly MyTech::native::Foo
   {
        public:
            Foo() { m_var = 1.0f; }
            float m_var;
   };

   public ref class Foo  // implicitly MyTech::managed::Foo because of ref.
   {
      Foo(native::Foo *native)  
      {
         m_native = native;
      }

      native::Foo *m_native;
   };
}
```

and could write **class managed::Foo** instead of **ref class Foo**

.. and dump that ref from the syntax as it's confusing to have two ways to specify the same thing.